# Problems installing R on Linux CentOS 6.3

Tags: r, centos

When installing R on Linux CentOS 6.3 I get the following:

```
Error: Package: R-core-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: kernel-headers
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1
```

This is after I install the epel 6 via:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

then trying:

```
yum install R
```

Comment: Maybe the dependencies didn't all get installed? Can you adding the libjpeg and kernel headers packages explicitly?

Comment: The libjpeg piece appears to be a known incompatibility with 6.3: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=980135

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can install the missing packages by downloading rpm and install using rpm command

[libjpeg.so.62](http://pkgs.org/download/libjpeg.so.62%28%29%2864bit%29) and [kernel-headers](http://pkgs.org/search/?keyword=kernel-headers&search_on=name&distro=82)

To install .rpm package use the following steps

> rpm -iv package.rpm

Try

> yum install R

After that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows Azure CentOS 6.3 instance, you may have to run:

```
sudo yum --disableexcludes=main install kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.openlogic.x86_64
```

See:

- [Openlogic Centos 6.3 image: no kernel-headers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b2770524-07a4-418d-8e03-6bd8634fa107/openlogic-centos-63-image-no-kernelheaders?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)
- [Azure VM (OpenLogic CentOS 6.3): no kernel-headers](https://superuser.com/questions/527416/azure-vm-openlogic-centos-6-3-no-kernel-headers)