# Installing R on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, r, installation, rhel6

my questions is similar to this one - 
[Problems installing R on Linux CentOS 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086262/problems-installing-r-on-linux-centos-6-3)

I installed epel, but when I run yum install R, I get the two dependency problems -

Error: Package: R-core-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)

Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex

I tried installing texinfo-tex using the rpm file from - 
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15993086/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

However, this takes me into a long tree of missing dependencies. I downloaded and tried installing 5 different rpm files and each time there were some missing dependencies. Ans this was just one branch of this tree of dependencies. I figured, there has got to be a better way. Can some one help? This has been driving me nuts.

Edit: Another option I'm trying is building R from source. Not sure if this will work given the missing packages though. For now however, it says it can't find a fortran compiler ("No F77 compiler found"). I installed gcc, thinking that it would have one, but apparently not.

Answer (score 9):

on RHEL6.4 do

subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms

yum install texinfo-tex

rpm -ivh http://mirror.unl.edu/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum install R

cheers Marten

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same problem and have spent about 3 hours attempting to find a yum repository out there for RHEL 6 that can solve this problem.  So far, it appears that whoever added this dependency didn't actually try and install it once they added the dependency.  These dependency mappings don't appear to exist anywhere in any repo that I can find.

…

So I got frustrated and tried this command

yum install texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm

and it worked

```
    Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
CentALT                                                  |  951 B     00:00     
elrepo                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00     
epel/metalink                                            |  13 kB     00:00     
epel-testing/metalink                                    |  13 kB     00:00     
mongodb                                                  |  951 B     00:00     
puppetlabs-enterprise-extras                             | 1.9 kB     00:00     
remi                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
rhel-source                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-6                                     | 1.8 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
scl_python27                                             | 2.9 kB     00:00     
scl_ruby193                                              | 2.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Examining texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm: texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64
Marking texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package texinfo-tex.x86_64 0:4.13a-8.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package       Arch     Version         Repository                         Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 texinfo-tex   x86_64   4.13a-8.el6     /texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64   387 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 387 k
Installed size: 387 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64                               1/1 
  Verifying  : texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64                               1/1 

Installed:
  texinfo-tex.x86_64 0:4.13a-8.el6                                              

Complete!

# yum install R
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.0.1-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: R-devel = 3.0.1-2.el6 for package: R-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.1-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: R-java-devel = 3.0.1-2.el6 for package: R-devel-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-core-devel = 3.0.1-2.el6 for package: R-devel-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.1-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.1-2.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package               Arch            Version              Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 R                     x86_64          3.0.1-2.el6          epel           19 k
Installing for dependencies:
 R-core-devel          x86_64          3.0.1-2.el6          epel           90 k
 R-devel               x86_64          3.0.1-2.el6          epel           19 k
 R-java-devel          x86_64          3.0.1-2.el6          epel           19 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       4 Package(s)

Total download size: 147 k
Installed size: 326 k
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I downloaded the texinfo rpm file from http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15993086/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm.html and then ran the command and texinfo is installed. This half solves the problem. There is one more missing dependency.. libjpeg that R still requires.

Answer (score 2):

**Installing R on 6.6 RHEL 64 bit machine**

After going through many pages i found this steps, so thought to share as a quick steps:

**wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm**

"It's a package which is preferred for RHEL machine."

**sudo yum install tcl**

“The Tcl package contains the Tool Command Language, a robust general-purpose scripting language. This package is known to build and work properly using an LFS-7.7 platform. This package is known to build and work properly using the gcc-5 compiler.”

**sudo yum clean all**

“Cleans the yum cache”

**sudo yum install R**

“For installing R”

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.unl.edu/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

The second is:

```
#yum install R
```

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: Hi Alok.. this gives me the following error -
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
error: skipping http://mirror.unl.edu/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm - transfer failed

Comment: http://mirror.unl.edu/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm try this it should work now

Comment: I tried this.. it said "package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed". And then, yum install R gives me the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Any advice on how to get a fortran compiler installed instead? That might help me build from source. I've tried yum install g77, gfortran, gcc-fortran, but it can't find any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo yum groupinstall “Development Tools”

This installs development tools which includes all compilers.
I am also trying to install the same. Tried building from source. Now trying to build with yum. Let's see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

"I tried this.. it said "package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed". "

But not enabled... See: https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/installing-r-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-5/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue,  And many seem to be getting stuck on this.
The dependencies are available in the RedHat Repo [rhel-6-server-optional-rpms].  Enable the repo and R should install.