# Installing R on RHEL dependencies - libjpeg

Tags: r, installation, rhel

This is pertaining to this question I asked earlier -

[Installing R on RHEL 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747640/installing-r-on-rhel-6)

So, there were two missing dependencies in installing R on RHEL, texinfo and libjpeg. The first answer to the question solves the texinfo dependency. I set out to solve the libjpeg dependency in a similar manner. A Google search led me to this site -

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libjpeg

However, this one has many rpm files apparently for different flavors of RHEL (?) like alpha, i386, etc. I tried two random rpm's and none of them worked. I tried the apha one and got an error saying not compatible architecture and the i386 one said "--.rpm does not update installed package; Nothing to do". But when I try and install R, it still can't find the libjpeg. So, is there a way to understand if and which rpm from the long list on the above web site I should use so I can install R?

Edit - I went to this link: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)

and tried the first rpm. It seemed to work, but required yet another dependency.. libc.so.6 this time

Error: Package: libjpeg62-62.0.0-25.3.x86_64 (/libjpeg62-62.0.0-25.3.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)

And searching for this one on google isn't leading me to the rpm.

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91619/libc-so-6glibc-2-1464bit  this would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker